# implementing an unordered map within an unordered map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I am reading data from a file and trying to set it up as an unordered map within another unordered map so that I can have 2 keys for a certain value. The file contains vertices and the distance from one to the other. I am using this code to read from the file and create the ordered maps but it doesn't work. I looked for examples on how to implement the unordered maps but I didn't find anything online.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <set>


int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string,std::unordered_map<std::string,int>> left_vertex;
    std::set<std::string> vertices;
    int i=0,j=0,distance = 0;
    std::string start_vertex = "",outer_key = " ",inner_key = " ";
    std::unordered_map<std::string,std::unordered_map<std::string,int>>::iterator it;
    std::set<std::string>::iterator it2;

    for(std::string line;std::getline(std::cin,line);)
    {
        std::stringstream line_stream(line);

        for(std::string token;std::getline(line_stream,token,' ');)
        {
            if(i==0)
            {
                start_vertex = token;
                break;
            }

            if(j==0)
            {
                outer_key = token;
                vertices.insert(outer_key);
            }

            if(j==1)
            {
                inner_key = token;
            }
            if(j==2)
            {
                distance = std::stoi(token);
            }
            j++;

        }

        for(it2 = vertices.begin();it2!=vertices.end();it2++)
        {
            if(*it2 == outer_key)
            {
                //left_vertex.insert(std::make_pair(outer_key,std::make_pair(inner_key,distance)));
                left_vertex[outer_key][inner_key]=distance;
            }
            else
            {
                left_vertex[outer_key] = std::make_pair(inner_key,distance);
            }
        }
        outer_key = " ";
        inner_key = " ";
        distance = 0;
        j=0;
        i++;

    }

    for(it = left_vertex.begin(); it != left_vertex.end();it++)
    {
        std::cout<<it->first<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the file that I am reading from looks like this.

```
A 
A B 1
A C 5
B C 2
B D 4
C D 1
C E 4
D E 2
```

the first line is the starting vertex. after that the 3 element in each line represents the distance from the first element to the second element in each line.

Comment: Is the file always sorted?

Comment: yes the file will always be sorted

Comment: "..but it doesn't work." - so... debug it?  What *does* this code do?

Comment: And can the vertex-names be trivially mapped to and from a range of consecutive integers? Those are much easier to handle than strings. If not, consider creating such a mapping before further processing.

Comment: It's supposed to read the file and create an unordered map within an unordered map. It will use the first element of each line as a key to the inner map and the second element in each line will be the key to the distance value between outer and inner key.  In the end the map will be used to implement a shortest path algorithm

Comment: @user3325937: It's supposed to read...: Is that the goal in itself, or only a first step before doing the work you actually want to do? Because it seems hilariously inefficient that way, think different: Map the vertex name to the vertex-id (0-based, if at all possible algorithmic, though a map might be needed), store the relationship-info in one vector, and the neccessary indexes in a second (for every vertex, the position directly after the last distance/vertex-pair).

Comment: @Deduplicator it is the first step to do the actual work. But I will try your suggestion.

Comment: These type of problems are much easier solved by having something along the lines of `std::unordered_map< std::pair< string, string >, int >`.

Comment: @Ylisar: Unbelievably inefficient.

Comment: @Deduplicator: How so? It will have way better memory behavior than `std::unoredered_map< string, std::unoredered_map< string, int > >`. The only thing that could keep it down is the comparison function, in which case that could easily be solved by using a straight hash instead.

Comment: Okay, I think you're referring to the duplication of strings, I'll throw `boost::flyweight< string >` at it if that's the case ;)

Comment: @Ylisar: You should not only look at wasted space but also at wasted time (`string`s, any way you slice it, are way worse than `int`s for both). Compare with my big comment above, and think that you will have to access the data repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered two problems in your code:

- The line with `std::make_pair` just didn't compile.
- Your print strategy was wrong for this kind of sophisticated double-map.

Other than that your code did pretty much what you wanted it to do.
I took the liberty of reformatting it and making it a little shorter and simpler - you had a couple of unnecessary `for` loops.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_map<std::string, int>> doubleMap;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_map<std::string, int>>::iterator it;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int>::iterator it2;
    std::string key1, key2, distanceStr;

    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line); // Read the unwanted line
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        std::stringstream line_stream(line);
        std::getline(line_stream, key1, ' ');
        std::getline(line_stream, key2, ' ');
        std::getline(line_stream, distanceStr, ' ');

        doubleMap[key1][key2] = std::stoi(distanceStr);
    }

    for (it = doubleMap.begin(); it != doubleMap.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << it->first << std::endl;
        for (it2 = it->second.begin(); it2 != it->second.end(); ++it2) {
            std::cout << "  " << it2->first << " " << it2->second << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code when I input your file is this:

```
A
  C 5
  B 1
D
  E 2
C
  D 1
  E 4
B
  D 4
  C 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your datastructure with a double unordered_map is intersting.  However the code you use looks a little bit too complex.

Just replace your `for(it2 ...)` loop block with the following:

```
    if (i!=0)   // for the first line the data is irrelevant
        left_vertex[outer_key][inner_key] = distance;  // just insert !
```

Adding the following output code at the end:

```
for (it = left_vertex.begin(); it != left_vertex.end(); it++) {
    std::cout << it->first << std::endl<<"\t";
    for (auto x : it->second)
        std::cout << x.first << x.second<<" ";
    cout << endl; 
}
```

Permits to sse the result:

```
A
        B1 C5
B
        C2 D4
C
        D1 E4
D
        E2
```

**Some other suggestions:**

For your reading of `line_stream`, you could as well write somethin like `line_stream>>outer_key>>inner_key>>distance;` which would make counter j and intermediary token useless.

You could also check at the end, if vertices is consistent with the inner_keys, as this is currently not ensured.